# Is Windows XP and XAMPP able to render complex development sites in Drupal 7?

Tags: debugging

I am developing a site, and in the Linux server it goes very fast, with peaks of memory of 40 MBytes, according to Devel module. However, when I test it exactly the same in Windows XP and Xampp, it takes a long time to serve each page, even if the memory usage is a little less - (25 Mb !? ). When Drupal 7 is freshly installed, with default configuration, it is very fast, but when I add modules, etc., it takes ages to load any page, even if the memory usage is low as I said. Memory limit of PHP is 128 Megabytes.

Comment: This is more of a system related question with Xampp rather than a Drupal related question.

Comment: This is a too broad question, but comparing XO with an OS built for servers specifically is not the same. Win XP has services for multimedia devices, windows update, and several other features suitable for a desktop OS. XP has NTFS file system, its own drivers, etc. to answer your question, yes, win XP can run a complex site, but your mileage would be better if you use an OS specifically designed for servers. Ubuntu for desktop comes with KDE or Gnome for the desktop features. It's not what we install in servers.

Comment: @Cesar See if you can get [Wincache](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/wincache-extension) going on that platform. Scroll down to the bottom of the linked page and select your version.

Comment: Have you tried Acquia Dev Desktop? It's a WAMP stack that works great on every machine I've tried (not XP however)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my question was not well formatted. It happens that the theme installed was rebuilding on every page load, and that consumed lots of RAM. I switched off the rebuild, and it worked very fast, as expected. It was not a specific OS problem, but a performance one due to theme rebuilding